# JavaScript Comparision fails, when retrieving the values from the Servlet through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

Using the function `storeSessionId()` , I retrieved the value of storedSession and assigned to sessionId from the servlet using AJAX.

```
   var storedSession;
   var sessionId;       

function storeSessionId(){
    try
    {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                storedSession = xmlhttp.responseText.toString();
                sessionIdValue(storedSession);

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","JoinAction?subject="+subject+"&userId="+userId+"&secureKey="+secureKey,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.description);
    }
}
```

When I compared the `sessionId!=null` only my div will be displayed else it cannot be  displayed.

But even if I got `sessionId==null` also, my div was displayed. My div was displayed in both the condition.

```
function sessionIdValue(storedSession){
    sessionId = storedSession;
    if(sessionId != null && sessionId != "null"){
        document.getElementById("div").style.display="inline";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried .But getting value as null only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is  ,

```
function trim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}
```

I passed the sessionId value in to trim()...

Thanks for all who helped me..

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `sessionId` is an empty string `""`.  Try changing the condition to

```
if(sessionId && sessionId != "null")
```

This will just check for a truthy value which the empty string is not.

Comment: No I am getting value in console through my servlet as "sessionId : null"

Comment: getting sessionId is null in alertbox.

Comment: Is "sessionId : null" the entire response? If so you need to parse out the value.  I'd use a regex to isolate the value, something like `sessionId.match(/: (.+)/)[1] != "null";`  See http://jsfiddle.net/mhPry/

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `sessionId != null` which is incorrect.

Put `alert(sessionId)` to know the response value.

Try:

```
if(sessionId && sessionId != "null"){
 document.getElementById("div").style.display="inline";
}
```

First condition checks whether `sessionId` is not `undefined` and  then for `null` string.

Comment: Here I stored the sessionId value in javaScript only .So I can use only  == comparision . I think equals() is not available in javascript?

Comment: getting sessionId is null in alertbox.